# Javascript cross-origin redirection in JS modul

Tags: javascript, html, single-sign-on

I'm trying to import a js file in module Tag in HTML, like this:

```
<script type="module">
    import something from "./someotherthing.js";
</script>
```

In our organization we have a SSO - System, which controls access to the Files on the Server. This SSO System redirects the import on himself before redirecting to the File. 
Cause of this browsers (especially Safari) prevents this redirection by cross-origin sharing policy.
I can't modify the Header of the SSO system, is there any possibility to import even if there's a redirection?

Comment: Since I didn't make this work I ended up making the js files public.